# Listener hangs when trying to remove

Tags: c#, listener, trace

I have a button connected to the start and stop below.  After a number of button clicks the application hangs on Trace.Listeners.Remove(_listener).  Any idea why?

```
public void StartListener(ITraceTextSink sink)
{
    if (_listener != null) return;
    _listener = new TraceSource(sink);
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;
    Trace.Listeners.Add(_listener);
 }

public void StopListener()
{
    if (_listener == null) return;
    Trace.Listeners.Remove(_listener);
    _listener.Dispose();
    _listener = null;
}
```

Comment: The socket closes wait for an ACK from the client based on a timeout.  If you do not have a client connected properly it will hang.  First you should never close a connection from the server because there is a potential error that can occur if both the client and server tries to close the connection at the same time.  I would implement a Keep-Alive that will automatically close an idle connection.  Then test the the socket is closed before attempting to stop the connection.

Comment: Not sure I understand.   I"m using WPF trace items to the UI.

Comment: The listener is a TCP Socket.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info!  I'm going to try something else.